# Select Query Is Not Being Prepared

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Here i am implementing a select query to fetch data from table but no any row is been returned by my query.

below is my code that i am using:

```
if ((sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database))==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"DataBase OpeneD..!!");
    imageId=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    const char *slectImageIdQuery="SELECT * from ts_Gallary;";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, slectImageIdQuery, -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Query CREATED..!!");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            int iId=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            NSString *imgTtl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iId];
            NSLog(@"image id in while=%d",iId);
            [imageId addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imgTtl]];           
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"query could not be prepared");
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);        
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

My console display:

**2011-04-06 17:44:33.381 Tuscany[4680:207] DataBase OpeneD..!!
2011-04-06 17:44:33.382 Tuscany[4680:207] query could not be prepared**

Note: Here **dataFilePath** is method which return path of my database and **database** is sqlite3 object

No Error or exception is been thrown by my application.

What problem can there be and how can I detect the problem as well as solve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No Error or exception is been thrown
>   by my application.

Well, yeah, there is. Your call to sqlite3_prepare_v2() fails; it doesn't return SQLITE_OK.

What happens when you run this statement at your database's sqlite prompt?

```
SELECT * from ts_Gallary;
```

Try replacing this line

```
NSLog(@"query could not be prepared");
```

with something that will give you more information about the error. Include a call to sqlite3_errmsg().

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **semicolon(;)** from **const char *slectImageIdQuery="SELECT * from ts_Gallary;"**

like **const char *slectImageIdQuery="SELECT * from ts_Gallary"**

and its work properly.